# “where not equal to” in Couchbase

Tags: go, couchbase

I want to be able to use a “where not equal to” WHERE clause in Couchbase.

This code works to INCLUDE “Not Available” records *(once you set the Analyser to ‘keyword’)*

```
cbft.NewMatchQuery("Not Available").Field("Status"),
```

But I want to be able to return all records where the Status is anything other than “Not Available”.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the Go SDK, but have you tried to use the "Required, Optional, and Exclusion" operators (https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/fts/fts-query-types.html)? They probably are exactly what you need.